# How to dynamically allocate 2D array of pointer that's 64B aligned using posix_memalign

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-alignment

I have two arrays, `y_train` which is a 1D array, and `x_train` which is a 2D array. I need to dynamically allocate these two arrays using posix_memalign.
I did that for `y_train` correctly. where I convert `int y_train[4344]` into the following code.

```
   int* Y_train;
posix_memalign((void**)(&Y_train), 64, sizeof(int) * 4344);
```

Now, I want to convert `int x_train[4344][20];` in the same way but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a memory block of the complete size and assign it to a pointer of the correct type:

```
void *ptr;
posix_memalign(&ptr, 64, sizeof(int) * 4344);
int *Y_train = (int*)ptr;
posix_memalign(&ptr, 64, sizeof(int) * 20 * 4344);
int (*x_train)[20] = (int (*)[20])ptr;
```

Now the whole 2D array is correct aligned, but not all inner arrays are correct aligned, because the `20 * sizeof(int)` is not a multiple of `64`.

When you need every inner array of `20` `int`s to be aligned correctly, you have to add padding bytes, `12` `int`s, then every inner array has `128` bytes.

```
posix_memalign(&ptr, 64, sizeof(int) * 32 * 4344);
int (*x_train)[32] = (int (*)[32])ptr;
```

Just ignore the last `12` `int`s.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  What about the 1D arrat `int* Y_train;
posix_memalign((void**)(&Y_train), 64, sizeof(int) * 4344);` Is it correct ??

Comment: could you please update your answer with 1D array also

Comment: Also what do you mean by " but only every second inner array is correct aligned, because the 4344 * sizeof(int) is not a multiple of 64." ???

Comment: Do I need to type: `void *ptrr = Null; ` ??? Or it is file without `Null ` ???

Comment: But I need the size to be `4344` and I need to use `posix_memalign`. I can't change the size of array.  Also, I how I can do this " either have to alloc 20 single arrays"

Comment: I tried your answer today with compiler. it gave this error. `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int (*)[20]’ [-fpermissive]
     int(*array_X_set)[20] = ptr;`

Comment: yes, C++ requires the cast, I added it. sorry.

Comment: Yes It works now. Thank you very much mch you are great. I have another question. How I can pass `X_train` and `Y_train` to function like `void split_dataset(int fold, int** X_train, int* Y_train`  and how to call that function.

Comment: You can change the function to `void split_dataset(int fold, int (* X_train)[20], int* Y_train)` and call it with `split_dataset(5, x_train, Y_train);`

Comment: Okay, I will try and back to you

Comment: `posix_memalign(&ptr, 64, sizeof(int) * 32 * 4344);
int (*x_train)[32] = (int (*)[32])ptr;` In this way, didn't we change the size of array from `[4344][20] ` into `[4344][32]` ??

Comment: Yes, then you need to use `32` instead of `20`, in the function parameter too.

Comment: I read some documentation. it said that `posix_memalign` returns `error` if `The value of the alignment parameter is not a power of two multiple of sizeof(void *).` I didn't understand this in my case ??

Comment: power of two ==> `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 ...`. `sizeof(void*)` is either `4` or `8` on your system. `64` is either `16 * 4` or `8 * 8`, so it's fine.

Comment: okay, but `posix_memalign(&ptr, 64, sizeof(int) * 4344);
int *Y_train = (int*)ptr;` here `4344` is not multiple of `64`. So it will not be correctly aligned. Rright ??

Comment: It will be correct aligned, as it is only a 1D array. When you want a 2D array with a non power of 2 size, not all inner arrays are aligned.